# ASP.NET MVC 3 Route parameter problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I have a desktop system that calls a PHP script (script.php) and I send a parameter called by "x" to this script (ex: script.php?x=123), but now the PHP scripts are being rewritten in ASP.NET/MVC, but I can't change the desktop system, then I've created a route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute("ScriptPHP",
    "myscript/script.php",
    new { controller = "MyController", action = "MyAction", x = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

The problem is: MyAction receives a parameter named "id" (`MyAction(int id)`), and this route works only if I call "script.php?id=123".

How do I send the parameter "x" and this route convert "x" to "id" parameter name? It's possible?

NOTE: I can't change the action parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your action method to be the following

```
public ActionResult MyAction(int x)
{

}
```

Once you do that, it'll work as you expect.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't change the parameters, but your response has opened my mind and I'll create a new action only for this route, thanks. I can't believe I did not think of it before, sometimes we seek hard solutions for easy things.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/jasonconway/archive/2009/10/22/aliasing-and-localizing-routes-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx). You can probably extend it to alias query params.

Comment: Thanks @Mrchief, but this is a very ugly solution, but thanks for response.